# How to generate a big integer in Matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, cryptography, matrix-multiplication

**I want to know if Matlab can handle big integers, for example integers on 7000 bits.**

I would need them for a [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) application which uses matrices as ciphertexts, multiply and add them, something derived from this work https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/340.pdf, pag.24-25. As Matlab works well with matrices, I want to experiment if the Matlab implementation is faster than the C++ one.

Comment: matlab is interpreted, no?

Comment: uhhh not sure if Matlab implementation is faster than C++, but you can potentially just store your big integer as an Array(Vector/Matrix) of bits or something even smarter.

Comment: The Alternative is use the vpa function in Symbolic Math which allows you 2^29 +1 significant decimal at a VERY COSTLY process